# How to show content on button click if pattern matches in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying show content in a div when a user click on a button. I have three button **test connection src** , **test connection dest**, **next**.

When I click on **test connection src** if there is no input it should display message but when user click on input field it should hide the message, right now I am able to show the message but when I click on input field it is not hiding 
same when **test connection src** clicked if the input field matches the with pattern that is regex it show display message connection successful,
right now I am not able to show connection successful in `<div id = "inp_src_success"></div>` and `<div id = "inp_dest_success"></div>`

Same goes for button  **test connection dest**

**next** button click should be enabled only once the both become successful

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#test_btn_src").on("click", function(){
            var inpsrc = document.getElementById('inp_src').value;
            //alert(inpsrc);
            if(inpsrc.trim() == null || inpsrc.trim() == "") {
              document.getElementById('inp_src1').innerHTML = 'IP src should be filled out';
            }
            else {
              $("inp_src").keypress(function(key){
                  if (key){
                      $("inp_src1").hide();
                  }
              });
            }
          });
          $("#test_btn_dest").on("click", function(){
            var inpdest = document.getElementById('inp_dest').value;
            //alert(inpsrc);
            if(inpdest.trim() == null || inpdest.trim() == "") {
              document.getElementById('inp_dest1').innerHTML = 'IP src should be filled out';
            }
            else {
              $("inp_dest").keypress(function(key){
                  if (key){
                      $("inp_dest1").hide();
                  }
              });
            }
          });

          document.getElementById("mybtn").onclick = function () {
              location.href = "www.google.com";
          };
        });
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
      <body>
        <div id = "inp_src_success"></div>

        <div>
          <label>Enter Source Server IP Here</label>
          <input  id = "inp_src" name="txtbox_ip_src" minlength="7" maxlength="15" class="form-control" type="text"
              placeholder="Source Server Ip:"
              pattern="(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
              required onkeypress="myFunction()" />
              <div id = "inp_src1"></div>
              <button id  = "test_btn_src" class="btn btn-primary success" type="button" style=" font-size: 10px; margin-top:7px;">Test Connection Src</button>
        </div>
        <div id = "inp_dest_success"></div>
        <div>
          <label>Enter Destination Server IP Here</label>
            <input id = "inp_dest" name="txtbox_ip_src" minlength="7" maxlength="15" class="form-control" type="text"
                placeholder="Destination Server Ip:"
                pattern="(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
                required  onkeypress="myFunction1()" />
            <div id = "inp_dest1"></div>
            <button id  = "test_btn_dest" class="btn btn-primary success" type="button" style=" font-size: 10px; margin-top:7px;">Test Connection Dest</button>
        </div>
        <button  id = "mybtn" class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: give me any test ip which can validate your regex..

Comment: @AjayKumar `0.0.0.0` will validate it, for example

Comment: hye @AjayKumar you can go for any ip address

Comment: can i give you a regex to validate for ip and then try that what you think?

Comment: @AjayKumar 123.76.98.98 take this ip as an example as i am just taking a example

Comment: here you go brother.

Comment: @ParthTiwari if you check my answer and get expected results then please mark it as resolved as my answer was first posted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of changes that I would suggest you make in your JavaScript. It can do with a lot of improvement. Since you will be using these elements in a few places I suggest adding global variables for these, so that it's easier to work with.

See the snippet below. I will add comments. I won't be using jQuery, but vanilla JavaScript.

I added `type="submit"` to the buttons to use the browser's built in validator.

So in the example snippet, you will see a few ways you can validate.

I wrapped your form in `form` tags, since this is a form, and you're doing validation. I assume you will be submitting the form as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Global vars, to be reused.
  var sourceValid = false;
  var destinationValid = false;

  var btnTestSrc = document.getElementById("test_btn_src");
  var btnTestDest = document.getElementById("test_btn_dest");
  var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("mybtn");

  btnSubmit.disabled = true;

  var txtInpSrc = document.getElementById("inp_src");
  var txtInpDest = document.getElementById("inp_dest");

  var inpSrc1 = document.getElementById('inp_src1');
  inpSrc1.style.display = "none";
  var inpDest1 = document.getElementById('inp_dest1');
  inpDest1.style.display = "none";
  //

  //Add an event listener to the button. Same as the jQuery alternative that you used.
  btnTestSrc.addEventListener("click", function() {
    sourceValid = InputHasValue(txtInpSrc);
    inpSrc1.style.display = sourceValid ? "none" : "block";

    if (sourceValid && destinationValid)
      btnSubmit.removeAttribute("disabled");
    else
      btnSubmit.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  });

  //This event listener will do validation before you click the button
  txtInpSrc.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    inpSrc1.style.display = InputHasValue(this) ? "none" : "block";
  });

  btnTestDest.addEventListener("click", function() {
    destinationValid = InputHasValue(txtInpDest);
    inpDest1.style.display = destinationValid ? "none" : "block";

    if (sourceValid && destinationValid)
      btnSubmit.removeAttribute("disabled");
    else
      btnSubmit.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  });

  txtInpDest.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    inpDest1.style.display = InputHasValue(this) ? "none" : "block";
  });

  btnSubmit.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("submit");
  });

  //Repeat on Dest
});

function InputHasValue(input) {
  var val = input.value.trim();

  return val ? true : false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form>
    <div id="inp_src_success"></div>

    <div>
      <label>Enter Source Server IP Here</label>
      <input id="inp_src" name="txtbox_ip_src" minlength="7" maxlength="15" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Source Server Ip:" pattern="(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
        required />
      <br />
      <div id="inp_src1">IP src should be filled out</div>
      <button id="test_btn_src" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary success" type="button" style=" font-size: 10px; margin-top:7px;">Test Connection Src</button>
    </div>
    <div id="inp_dest_success"></div>
    <div>
      <label>Enter Destination Server IP Here</label>
      <input id="inp_dest" name="txtbox_ip_src" minlength="7" maxlength="15" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Destination Server Ip:" pattern="(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
        required />
      <br />
      <div id="inp_dest1">IP dest should be filled out</div>
      <button id="test_btn_dest" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary success" type="button" style=" font-size: 10px; margin-top:7px;">Test Connection Dest</button>
    </div>
    <button id="mybtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: hey @Marius It's not showing successful connection entering IP address in both the section

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <body>
        <div id = "inp_src_success"></div>

        <div>
          <label>Enter Source Server IP Here</label>
          <input  id = "inp_src" name="txtbox_ip_src" minlength="7" maxlength="15" class="form-control" type="text"
              placeholder="Source Server Ip:"
              pattern="(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
              required onkeypress="myFunction()" />
              <div id="inp_src1"></div>
              <br>
              <button id  = "test_btn_src" class="btn btn-primary success" type="button" style=" font-size: 10px; margin-top:7px;">Test Connection Src</button>
        </div>
        <div id = "inp_dest_success"></div>
        <div>
          <label>Enter Destination Server IP Here</label>
            <input id = "inp_dest" name="txtbox_ip_src" minlength="7" maxlength="15" class="form-control" type="text"
                placeholder="Destination Server Ip:"
                pattern="(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
                required  onkeypress="myFunction1()" />
            <div id = "inp_dest1"></div>
            <br>
            <button id  = "test_btn_dest" class="btn btn-primary success" type="button" style=" font-size: 10px; margin-top:7px;">Test Connection Dest</button>
        </div>
        <button  id = "mybtn" class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("#test_btn_src").on("click", function(){

            var inpsrc = document.getElementById('inp_src').value;
            //alert(inpsrc);
            if(inpsrc.trim() == null || inpsrc.trim() == "") {
              document.getElementById('inp_src1').innerHTML = 'IP src should be filled out1';
            }
            else {

                      $("#inp_src1").hide();

            }
          });
          $("#test_btn_dest").on("click", function(){
            var inpdest = document.getElementById('inp_dest').value;
            //alert(inpsrc);
            if(inpdest.trim() == null || inpdest.trim() == "") {
              document.getElementById('inp_dest1').innerHTML = 'IP src should be filled out';
            }
            else {

                      $("#inp_dest1").hide();

            }
          });

          document.getElementById("mybtn").onclick = function () {
              location.href = "www.google.com";
          };
        });
```

Comment: there no succesfull connection message on button click as well as there is next button is still working

Comment: is the message show and hide issue resolved using my solution?